# JQuery Masonry -- expand div's over other div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm making something similar to an iphone layout (a bunch of tiles with pictures/numbers that you can click on to get more information).  After the layout has been set, I'd like a click-event to expand one of the tiles to be full screen.  Right now, it moves the tiles so that the layout is re-adjusted.  Is it possible to get masonry to stop rendering so that one tile get's enlarged over the other tiles?

The following is what I've tried (but unsuccessfully).  Note: It uses d3.js to generate the div's for masonry to use.

```
function drawGrid(divname,orders)
{   
var mydiv = d3.select(divname);
$(divname).masonry({
    itemSelector: '.g1',
    isAnimated: true,
    //isResizable: true
});

var myd = mydiv.selectAll("div");
var mygs = myd.data(orders,function(d){ return d.orderid;})
    .enter().append("div")  
    .attr("class","g1")
    .append("g");

var x1 = mygs.append("div")
        .attr("class","tickerdiv")
        .text(function(d){ return d.ticker; }); 


var ActiveOrder = "1";
$(divname+' .g1').click(function() {  
    //$(this).show('maximised');
    console.log("clicked")

    $(this).animate({"display":"none","position": "absolute",
        "top": "0",
        "left": "0",
        "width": "100%",
        "height": "100%",
        "z-index": 1000 }, 1000);
});
var x = [];
x.redraw = function(o)
{           
    x1.text(function(d){ return d.ticker; });
}
return x;
}
```

and from the css file:

```
.g1 { min-height:80px; width: 100px; margin: 15px; float: left; background-color: RGB(223,224,224); border-radius: 10px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; padding-top: 20px;}
```

Comment: see above...let me know if you need more to go off of

Comment: Masonry use a bin-packing algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Ok, my first answer was not useful here - absolute positioning won't work in case of masonry's/Isotope's relatively positioned container with absolute positioned elemens contained therein; the solution is rather to take the content of a masonry/Isotope element out of the DOM on click and append it temporarily to the body. You can see the basic idea [in my dirty swedish sandbox](http://www.hopfnordin.se/demo.html)

```
<!-- masonry/Isotope item large -->

<div class="item large">
    <div class="header">
        <p>Click here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="minimised">
        <p>Preview</p>
    </div>
    <div class="maximised">
        <p>Content</p>
        <button id="screen-overlay-on">Screen overlay on</button>
        <div id="screen-overlay-background"></div>
        <div id="screen-overlay-content">
            <p>Content</p>
            <button id="screen-overlay-off">Screen overlay off</button>
        </div>​
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#screen-overlay-on').click(function(){

        var sob = $('#screen-overlay-background').detach();
        var soc = $('#screen-overlay-content').detach();

        sob.appendTo('body');
        soc.appendTo('body');

        $('#screen-overlay-background').toggleClass("active");
        $('#screen-overlay-content').toggleClass("active");
    });

    $('#screen-overlay-background, #screen-overlay-off').click(function(){
        $('#screen-overlay-background').toggleClass("active");
        $('#screen-overlay-content').toggleClass("active");
    });

});
</script>
```

With CSS like

```
#screen-overlay-background {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #333;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 1000;
}

#screen-overlay-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
height: 240px;
width: 320px;
margin: -120px 0 0 -160px;
background-color: #FFF;
z-index: 1000;
}

#screen-overlay-background.active, #screen-overlay-content.active {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Added my code above.  I tried to get your code to work, but masonry still moves objects around it.  Also, only 100% width works (100% height does not).

Comment: And - did you try the updated answer and looked at the online sandbox? Basically, you can make anything full screen this way, probably skipping that close dialog window which is a secondary overlay not needed in your case I believe.

Comment: trying it now...i'm kind of hesitant to say it'll work because i'd like to expand the div to full screen with animation from it's current location

Comment: Without having tried, you should be able to animate or CSS transform the screen overlay background, because after re-insertion into the DOM, it's just like any other element. I'd get the principle to work first - and then concentrate on animations and effects in step two...

Comment: Quickly hacked in the necessary change. If you look at the sandbox again, you see that you can animate it after re-insertion into the DOM.

Comment: you're amazing!  I still need it to expand from it's original location, but I think jquery can figure out it's original location.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Be aware that masonry (I'm usually more fond of its bigger brother Isotope) positions each element absolute in relation to the relative positioned container - therefore, you can't just use the simple DOM related way of finding their location (centres or top left corners) to animate outwards from. Isotope has an option called itemPositionDataEnabled that retreives the elements' positions. Also, you need to put in a toggle that animates the full screen element back to what it was; otherwise it will simply blip full screen without animation. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Yes, David DeSandro's plugins are worth every $ and the best thing is that one can get all kinds of sites to work and look stunning without nasty hover effects and awful old-style menus - which don't work on smartphones or tablets, hehehe :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a :hover to the element in css and change the z-index.  You could easily change this on click with a class as well...

```
.item {
    z-index:1
}

.item:hover{
    z-index:2500;
}
```